# Multiple forms with readonly and multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dynamically generated amount of forms on a page with readonly set on all of the fields as well as a css class. Each form has it's own edit button in an anchor tag, which when clicked I would like to use removeClass() and attr('readonly', false) to reveal the form pertaining to that edit button. However if I supply the func with a class click handler this obviously reveals every form on the page which is not the desired result.

I don't need any code as I would like to work towards the solution myself but if anyone knows of any articles or something in particular that I should look at/use please fire away!!!

Thanks

Comment: How are you getting reference to the form that you call `removeClass()` on in the click handler?  Are you using some sort of reference to `$(this).parent()`, etc. to get the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! $('.prefRoute').delegate('.editPrefRoute', 'click' , function() { if($(this).parent().siblings('table').hasClass('selected')) { //DO STUFF HERE $(this).parent().siblings('table').removeClass('selected'); } else { $(this).parent().siblings('table').attr('class', 'selected'); //DO STUFF HERE } });

Answer (score 0):

In order to reference the specific form, you need to have some unique identifier.

You can do this in a couple ways.  The most straightforward is to have an id on each form, and each click handler can find the specific id.

However, a more generalized solution can be achieved assuming that the buttons are inside of their respective forms, like this.

```
<form>
  <!-- your form elements -->
  <button class="edit_button">Edit this form</button>
</form>
<form>
  <!-- your form elements -->
  <button class="edit_button">Edit this form</button>
</form>
<form>
  <!-- your form elements -->
  <button class="edit_button">Edit this form</button>
</form>
<form>
  <!-- your form elements -->
  <button class="edit_button">Edit this form</button>
</form>
.
.
.
```

and so on.

Then in your click handler, you can look for the first parent of the target of the click (the button) that is a form, and do stuff accordingly.

http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: SOLVED!

    $('.prefRoute').delegate('.editPrefRoute', 'click' , function() {

    if($(this).parent().siblings('table').hasClass('selected')) {

        //DO STUFF HERE
        $(this).parent().siblings('table').removeClass('selected');

    } else {

        $(this).parent().siblings('table').attr('class', 'selected');
        //DO STUFF HERE
    }
});